# Python Directories and Import statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

Let's say I have a directory structure as such

```
src\
  __init__.py
  notebooks\
    __init__.py
    foo.py
  utils\
    __init__.py
    db_connection.py
```

and in foo.py I have
   from utils.db_connection import *

Why does this fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, you do not have the "utils" directory in the searching list sys.path. You have two solutions. First is the move the foo.py into the higher folder, like:

```
│  foo.py
│  __init__.py
│
├─notebooks
│      __init__.py
│
└─utils
        db_connection.py
        db_connection.pyc
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
```

Otherwise, you could add the directory into the sys.path, like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import utils.db_connection
```

But the second one is really ugly~

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `src/` (or its full path) in `sys.path`.